# “onchange” not working after submitting the form in codemirror

Tags: javascript, php, html, codemirror

I have the form which is having textarea editor :

```
<textarea id="editor" name="field1"><?php if(isset($_POST['field1'])){echo htmlentities ($_POST['field1']);}?></textarea>
<script>
  var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'),{ mode:"text/x-java",lineNumbers: true });
  cm.on("change",function(){
       document.getElementById('demo11').innerHTML="Some action/message..."; }
```

I am submitting the form through dropdown menu:

```
<select class="tabb" name="launguage" id="launguage" onchange='this.form.submit()' >
```

Before submitting the form, whatever I am writing/pasting the content in textarea, my "onchange" function is working and I could see my corresponding message.

After submitting the form, for my retrieved content in the textarea through php, I could not see the "onchange" function working. Please help me.

Comment: It's really unclear what your problem is in your question. What happens when the form is submitted? Is the page reloaded somehow, and then your `onchange` binding doesn't work?

Comment: @Terry, Yes, page reload , form submitted other activity is happening. My problem is:  Onchange function works on textarea content before form submission. But after form submitted or page reload for new textarea content, the onchange function is not working.